Must these two operations be serialized if they are mutually exclusive operations?
Consider this example:
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

void close(int);
void use(int);
int create();

int main(){
  std::atomic<bool> is_shutdown = false;
  int fd = create();
  std::thread t1([&](){
    is_shutdown.store(true); // #0
    close(fd);  // #1
  });
  std::thread t2([&]{
     if(is_shutdown.load()){  // #2
         return;
     }
     use(fd);  // #3
  });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}

It was assumed that use(fd) would have an exception after fd is closed by close. It is possible that #2 still reads false after fd is closed by #1. So, the quick check is not reliable. Does it mean that these two operations must be serialized? In other words, they must be placed in critical sections such that they are exclusively executed.

Consider this scenario.  #2 happens on thread t2.  #1 happens on thread t1.  #3 happens on thread t2.  Kaboom.

I think with your last couple questions, you're overthinking subtle effects of memory ordering and missing the obvious ones that are explainable by simple interleaving.  No, it's not possible that #2 reads false if it happens after #1, because #1 happens after a store of true (to which you didn't give a number, so let me call it #0).  The bad case here is that #2 actually happens before #0.  Then #0 and #1 both happen.  Finally we go on to #3.  A very simple TOCTOU bug.

"It is possible that #2 still reads false after fd is closed by #1"  That's not correct.  Because is_shutdown is a std::atomic, you are assured that is shutdown is true during #1 and after #1.

In t2 there is a moment after determining that is_shutdown is false and before calling use(fd) when t1 could set is_shutdown to true and call close(fd). Assuming that use(fd) and close(fd) do something like what their names suggest, this is a data race and the behavior of the program is undefined.

The interesting question here is whether a scheme can be designed that allows threads that want to use(fd) to do so with only a read-only check.  Perhaps some of the machinery that Linux RCU uses to allow truly read-only lock-free readers while still eventually deallocating old copies could be of use here. This is a bit different because with RCU there's always a valid copy, but here we want threads to avoid calling use at all, rather than with a newer fd or something.

This question as written is not very interesting, as commenters point out it's a simple TOCTOU race.  Unless we read more into the question of whether they need to be in critical sections, e.g. the answer might be no if there's a different way to use atomic variables (and perhaps Linux system calls like membarrier https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/membarrier.2.html)

@NateEldredge [intro.races] p14 and [intro.races] p18 does not require a produced side effect is immediately visible to a load, which is also implied by [atomics.order] p11: The implementation should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads, and atomic loads should observe atomic stores, within a reasonable amount of time. That is, there exists a case that #2 still reads false but #1 is evaluated.

@DrewDormann See this comment and my above comment about a load can read "stale" value. Notes: The implementation should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads, and atomic loads should observe atomic stores, within a reasonable amount of time. This can imply a produced side effect cannot be visible to load in a short time.

@PeterCordes With the infrastructure of the C++ standard library, the use(fd) and close(fd) should be atomically executed in order, I think this way is to place them in critical sections.

Yes, one way to do that would be simple locking with critical sections.  But it's certainly reasonable to hope that there's a more efficient way than every call to use(fd) requiring a lock to be taken and released.  Like maybe an atomic integer where low couple bits can be a flag or two, and the higher bits a counter of how many threads are "active".  So preparing to close an fd might require the closer to set a flag and wait for the counter to decrease to zero to be sure all other threads had seen the flag when using the fd, so next time they'll be taking a lock.

@PeterCordes Ok, the essence of how you gave is still to make the use(fd) and close(fd) sequential. BTW, could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79003017/is-the-order-of-a-side-effect-in-the-modification-order-determined-by-when-the-s#comment139490987_79004731, I'm looking forward your answers, thanks.

Yes, of course.  Because that's what your code is trying to do, isn't it?  You tell us these things must not run concurrently or in the wrong order.  If you already knew this code didn't prevent that, what was the point?

@DrewDormann: I think that is xmh0511's point.  We agree that there could be a time lag between store #0 in t1 and when it is visible to t2, and that this could cause use and close to race even if #0 executes before #1 in real time.  But what I'm saying is that the code is broken even without that effect, and would be broken even on an implementation which strengthened p11 to guarantee instantaneous global visibility (e.g. a single-processor system): since it's also possible that #1 simply executes before #0 in real time, but #3 executes later.

So that's what I mean by my earlier comment - it seems a bit silly to trawl the standard in search of relatively subtle explanations for the incorrectness of this code, when it is already incorrect on its face for much more trivial reasons.

@NateEldredge Why can #1 simply execute before #0? Did you mean that #2 simply executes before #0, then #1 followed by #3?

Oh yes, sorry, all references to #1 above should be #2.  Yes, what you said is what I meant.

Yep. you need to serialize those operations. Even though you're using std::atomic for is_shutdown, there's still a race condition.
This is what can happen:
Thread t2 checks is_shutdown and sees it's false (#2).
Before t2 calls use(fd), thread t1 sets is_shutdown to true and closes fd (#1).
Now t2 calls use(fd) (#3) on a closed fd.
This means t2 might use fd after it's closed, which can cause errors. The check (is_shutdown.load()) and the action (use(fd)) are not happening together atomically.
You should use a mutex or some synchronization to make sure that when one thread is using fd, the other isn't closing it. That way either the thread sees that shutdown has happened and doesn't use fd, or it safely uses fd without worrying about it being closed.
